# Setting up permissions for multiple Linux instances accessing shared hard drive

Tags: linux, hard-drive, partitioning, permissions

I have a laptop with two hard drives, on one two Linux systems reside and on the other all my data are stored. There are two systems as one is for work and the other for personal usage (cannot stop procrastinating otherwise). I have a shared storage hard disk because some of the data I want to access from both systems, e.g. pictures, music, file transfer.

So far I could not manage to grasp Linux file permissions so that I can share/write/edit files from both systems on the shared storage. When I'm searching online for solutions there is mostly only information on shared home between Linux distros. But my Linux distros sit on two separate partitions (on the same hard disk).

Obviously I tried to execute commands like `chown` and `chmod` on both systems. This leads to a situation where I can access & write files from both systems but only delete from one of both systems. And it is not even consistent, because it depends on which system created the files, too (I think?).

However, the underlying questions are: How do the two Linux systems see each other? Where are file permissions stored? How to unify them between the two systems? Is this a generally bad set-up? Are there better alternatives?

Please let me know if I should specify anything (like commands I executed)!

I use arch btw *(well, actually manjaro)*

Answer (score 3):

(I assume the partition is in a Linux format, meaning not NTFS.)

You need to give world-permissions on the shared folder, for example by this command:

```
sudo chmod -R ugo+rwx /path/to/your/folder
```

Brief Explanation:

**sudo** : to elevate your privileges to root.
[**chmod**](https://linux.die.net/man/1/chmod): command to change the permissions
**-R** : recursive on sib-folders
**u** :- user
**g**:- group
**o** :- other
**Permissions**: read - r, write - w, execute (or search for directories) - x

While this will make the folder usable across the two Linux distributions,
you will probably still be in a situation where each distribution is using a different
user id. It would be better to synchronize the user ids on both distributions.

Permissions in both HFS+ and Linux-native filesystems are stored in terms of
user IDs (UIDs), which are numbers associated with usernames.
In Ubuntu, as in most modern Linux distributions, the first user is given a
UID of 1000 by default.

The better approach is to synchronize your account UIDs across both Linux distributions. You can easily change the UID value in Linux with the
[usermod](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/usermod.8.html)
command, as in:

```
usermod -u 501 dale
```

The post
[How to manage permissions on a shared volume for OSX and ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/315078/how-to-manage-permissions-on-a-shared-volume-for-osx-and-ubuntu)
contains some excellent advice for Linux:

> This command sets the UID for `dale` to 501. There are some
> significant caveats, though:
>
> - You should log out of the account you're modifying before you modify it. Trying to modify an in-use account will cause that account to
>   begin behaving strangely.
> - `usermod` must be used as `root`. You can execute it via `sudo`, but doing so from the account you're modifying is inadvisable in the
>   extreme. Thus, you'll need to either give `root` a password and log
>   into `root` directly or use `sudo` from a second user account.
> - The `usermod` command won't change the ownership of any files owned by the user in question. To adjust ownership of those files, you'll
>   need to locate them and then change their ownership with `chown`. Most
>   of the files will be in the user's home directory, so `chown -R dale: /home/dale`, typed as `root` after changing `dale`'s UID, will change
>   most of `dale`'s files to use the new UID number. Some of the user's
>   files may be located elsewhere, though. Typing `find / -uid 1000` will
>   find all the files that use the old UID (assuming it was 1000). Note
>   that this `find` command will probably take several minutes to
>   complete. To speed it up, unmount any filesystems on which you're sure
>   it will find no hits, such as FAT or NTFS volumes.
> - If you access FAT or NTFS volumes, their UID values are determined by options at mount time. If you use a GUI file manager, chances are
>   the UID value is set to whoever is running the file manager, so you
>   need do nothing special. If you mount the volume via an `/etc/fstab`
>   entry, though, you may need to adjust the UID value it specifies.
> - Ubuntu stores the minimum value it uses for UIDs in `/etc/login.defs`. If you fail to change the `UID_MIN` value in this
>   file, you'll likely discover that your account will seem to
>   "disappear" from the GUI login screen, and perhaps from some other
>   systems. Thus, you should edit that file.

Answer (score 0):

> When I'm searching online for solutions there is mostly only information on shared home between Linux distros. But my Linux distros sit on two separate partitions (on the same hard disk).

That's basically the same thing. There really is no difference between sharing an internal partition (such as /home) and sharing an external disk, if in both cases you're dealing with the same kind of filesystem.

> How do the two Linux systems see each other?

They don't.

> Where are file permissions stored?

Permissions and ownership information are part of each file's or folder's metadata – they're stored as part of the filesystem structure on the same disk that the file is in, next to the file's name, modification time, etc. There is no separate "permissions storage".

The file owner is stored by its numeric UID (as shown by `id` and `ls -l -n`).

Unlike Windows, generally Linux filesystems do not store anything that would help them distinguish same UID on different OS.

> How to unify them between the two systems?

If possible, change your user accounts to have identical UIDs on both systems.

For example, if a file says it's owned by user ID 1000 and your own account also has UID 1000, then you'll be recognized as that file's owner regardless of the OS. (Whether the user *names* match or not is irrelevant.)

The `usermod --uid` tool will let you change your own UID and will chown your home directory accordingly.

> I use arch btw (well, actually manjaro)

¯\_(ツ)_/¯